# Apache log processing on remote central log server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, logging, log-files

We have 50 RHEL Apache web-servers. We want all the Apache logs to be processed on a dedicated server meant for this purpose as we don't the dependencies of log processing application installed on our production servers.

What is the best way to accomplish it ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use syslog-ng

http://peter.blogs.balabit.com/2010/02/how-to-collect-apache-logs-by-syslog-ng/

Comment: Thats the collection part. And for log monitoring/searching, if you don't want to spend on splunk, you can try:  [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org/about) or [Logstash](http://logstash.net/docs/1.0.17/learn).

Answer (score 1):

The awnser Daya gave was very helpfull but i want to suggest something else.

How about creating a nfs share and link the httpdlog folder to that share. The share will be the central server of course.

Comment: This could cost a huge performance penalty.

Comment: if all server are connected in a internal network with a gigabit switch and networkcards i really wouldnt see any trouble

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be doing a lot of analysis, frequent queries, etc then it sounds like Splunk could fit the bill:

http://www.splunk.com

It's a great product but the downside is that the enterprise version is quite expensive. There is a free version with some limitations, it could be that this is suitable depending on the needs of your user base and the amount of data you intend to import. See the comparison between free and enterprise here:

http://www.splunk.com/view/free-vs-enterprise/SP-CAAAE8W

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the open-source [nxlog](http://nxlog.org) for log centralization.